# PDF not saving into "QuotePDF" object by detail page button using JQuery

Tags: apex, jquery

I made a vf page for generate a quote pdf Where i made a custom Detail page button
Which is Save this pdf into "QuotePDF" object which is related list to Quote object.
       When I click "create pdf" custom button then open up a dialog box which is opening through jquery used in custom button.And i save this pdf then no action perform.Please help me out.

Here my button code and apex class code.

Custom Detail page button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js')}
try{
jQuery(function() {
/*Append the jQuery CSS CDN Link to the Head tag.*/
jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />');




/*Create the HTML(DIV Tag) for the Dialog.*/
var html =
'<div id="dialog" title="PDF Preview"><iframe src="/apex/CreateQuote?id={!Quote.Id}" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>';
alert(html);
/*Check if the Dialog(DIV Tag) already exists if not then Append the same to the Body tag.*/
if(!jQuery('[id=dialog]').size()){
jQuery('body').append(html);
}

/*Open the jQuery Dialog.*/

jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: true,
modal: true,
width: 900,
height: 600,
show: {
effect: "show",
duration: 1000
},
hide: {
effect: "hide",
duration: 1000
},
buttons: {
"Save to Quote": function() {

sforce.apex.execute("quotePdfGeneratorController","saveAndClosePdf", 
{id:"{!Quote.Id}"});
alert('abcx');
jQuery("#dialog").on('dialogclose', function(event) {
location.replace('/{!Quote.Id}');
});
jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
},

Cancel: function() {
jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
}
});
});
}
catch(e){
alert('An Error has Occured. Error: ' + e);
}
```

Apex class

```
global class quotePdfGeneratorController {

    webService static void saveAndClosePdf(String quoteId){                
        Blob content;
        PageReference pdf = Page.CreateQuote;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',quoteId);
        system.debug('--pdf-->'+pdf);

        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            content = pdf.getContentAsPDF();        
        }else{
            content = blob.valueof('Some Test');
        }
        System.debug('content ==>'+content );
        //Blob pdf1 = pg.getcontentAsPdf();
        QuoteDocument doc = new QuoteDocument(Document = content, QuoteId = quoteId);
        Database.SaveResult insertResult = Database.Insert(doc, false);
        system.debug('--doc-->'+doc);

        Blob body;
        try {
            body = pdf.getContent();
        } catch (VisualforceException e) {
            body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
        }
        System.debug('body==>'+body);
        Quote quoteObj = [Select id,Quote_PDF_Number__c from Quote where id =: quoteId];
        List<QuoteDocument> quoteDoc = new List<QuoteDocument>([Select id from QuoteDocument where QuoteId =: quoteId]);
        if(quoteDoc != null && quoteDoc.size()>0){
            Integer docNum = quoteDoc.size();
            docNum ++;
            quoteObj.Quote_PDF_Number__c  = '_V'+docNum;
        }else{
            quoteObj.Quote_PDF_Number__c  = '_V1';
        }

        Document d = new Document();
            d.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            d.Body = body;
            d.Name = 'pdf_file.pdf';
            d.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
            d.Type = 'pdf';
            d.IsPublic = true;
            insert d;

        System.debug('d==>'+d);
     }  

      //Methord for Sending Email Page.
    webService static string saveAndEmailPdf(String quoteId){
        Blob content;
        //getting contact Email.
        quote quoteList = [SELECT id,ContactID,Email FROM quote WHERE id =: quoteId];

        PageReference pr = Page.CreateQuote;
        pr.getParameters().put('id', quoteId);
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            content = pr.getContentAsPDF();
        }else{
            content = blob.valueof('Some Test');
        }
        QuoteDocument doc = new QuoteDocument(Document = content, QuoteId = quoteId);
        Database.SaveResult insertResult = Database.Insert(doc, false);         
        // check for errors here and act according!
        //System.debug('Result: ' + insertResult);
        //System.debug('Quote PDF created: ' + doc.Id);  

        //upon completion redirect to quote
        String emailURL = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=' + quoteId + '&doc_id=' + doc.Id + '&retURL=%2F' + quoteId;
        if (quoteList.contactId != null){
            emailURL += '&p2_lkid=' + quoteList.contactId + '&doc_id=' + doc.Id;
        }
        System.debug('Quote Email URL: ' + emailURL);
        return emailURL;
    }

    webService static void ClosePdf(String quoteId){
        Quote quote = new Quote();
        system.debug('===quote===> '+quoteId);
        quote = [SELECT id,Quote_PDF_Number__c FROM quote WHERE id =: quoteId];
        if(quote != null){
            quote.Quote_PDF_Number__c = null;

            update quote;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From your code, it looks like you're trying to render the PDF in a 900x600 I-frame. You can render one in a new window of it's own, but I don't believe you can't render a "new" PDF using `renderAs` to an I-frame. Displaying an existing PDF that way is an entirely different matter. Until it actually renders, you don't have a "blob" to work with.

Comment: Maybe We can add button function in script tag in iframe and remove button function from dialog button then i believe it'll work.

Comment: You **CANNOT HAVE ANY ACTIVE CONTENT** in the source code that creates a PDF. You can use a script to call the source page from another one, but in all honesty, I expect that support for buttons will be disappearing from the platform within the next couple of years. They definitely will not be supported by lightning pages. The PDF will also need to be rendered to a window of it's own when being initially generated by the render engine. I don't believe you'll be able to create/render it in an iframe as it will need a unique uri.